# Is `std::wstring` a sort of class with reference counting?

Tags: c++

A few simple questions:

1. Is `std::wstring` a sort of class with reference counting like `std::vector`? As in, could I have it as a class member without specifying its size?
2. When I do this: `std::wstring string2 = string1;` (where string1 is also a `wstring` and has a value), would it copy the actual data or just the referring class?

I used to know this but I forget.

Comment: Please define "reference class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is std::wstring a sort of reference class like std::vector? As in, could I have it as a class member without specifying its size?

Yes, it is a "reference class", you can have it as a class member without specifying its size.

> When I do this: std::wstring string2 = string1; (where string1 is also a wstring and has a value), would it copy the actual data or just the referring class?

This will copy the data because you're calling the assignment operator defined within the wstring class.

If you want to change the "referring class" consider using a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "reference class" but yes you can have it as a class member without specifying the size:

   ```
   class MyClass
   {
   private:
       std::wstring _str;
   }
   ```
2. It would copy the actual data and you will have 2 different string objects with the same content.

It's worth noting that `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` are just typedefs for `std::basic_string<some_exact_type>`, so they all work the same way.